# Looking for a novel I read 25-30 years ago about a man drifting in the Bermuda Triangle

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I rack my brain about a science fiction novel I read about 25 - 30 years ago.

Unfortunately I don't remember much, but it was about a man drifting in the Bermuda Triangle and waiting for (I think) aliens to return. Then the fantastic story starts which is really a retrospective on the things that happened previously.

I remember that it was really grandiose and imposing. I think the triangle was some kind of portal or something. The end is the same as the beginning because the whole story was a retrospective view: The man drifting and waiting...

I was so impressed with the story that I read the night through... Now I want to find it again but cannot remember more :-( I tried all kinds of searches on Google and Amazon with "Bermuda Triangle" together with "science fiction" and "novel" but to no avail.

Perhaps anybody can give me some references/ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's all in the protagonist's head, but this immediately reminded me of Doris Lessing's *Briefing for a Descent into Hell* (1971). Powerful stuff.

From Lessing's site:

> Professor Charles Watkins (Classics), doomed to spin endlessly in the
>   currents of the Atlantic, makes a landfall at last on a tropical
>   shore. He discovers a reined stone city, participates - moon-dazed -
>   in bloody rituals in the paradisiacal forest, witnesses the savage war
>   of the Rat-dogs and is borne on the back of the lordly White Bird
>   across the sea of the dead. Finally, the Crystal claims him, whirling
>   him out into space on a breathtaking cosmic journey.